# Adjust image size dynamically without using IMG tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am currently developing a responsive website design that will change the layout of my page based on the resolution of the viewers device.  However, I currently use a piece of code to animate images on my site that calls images from a list of url's without using any HTML code.  The code looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dtmet.com/js/hanis_min.js"></script>
<body onload="HAniS.setup('filenames = https://www.dtmet.com/models/HRRR/2021032511/USA-HRRR-PTYPE-02.png, https://www.dtmet.com/models/HRRR/2021032511/USA-HRRR-PTYPE-03.png\n\
```

Then the images are displayed in a div like this...

```
<div id="handiv"></div>
```

All of the images are 1024x768.  Is there a way to change the size of the images dynamically so they can be displayed on smaller screens?

Comment: It is not good practice to make `onload` event inside the body tag. Better do it like `window.onload = function()`.

Comment: Are you prepared to create multiple images of different sizes, or a cropping script? If you are then use [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element with multiple sizes, if not then use CSS to make the image width:100% with [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), once you sorted that you can then think about animating them

Comment: your prob looking for window_size option, which you can get from [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight), or a specific element etc https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/hanis/examples/ha7a.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments and assistance.  It had been bugging me for a while, but I finally got it working with your help.